# Does the fixed point in the Brouwer's Fixed-Point Theorem have to be an interior point?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, fixed-point-theorems

As the question suggests, does the fixed point in the Brouwer's Fixed-Point Theorem have to be an interior point? Many thanks in advance.

To be clear, I'm using the statement of Brouwer's Fixed-Point Theorem from $\S$2.2 of Guillemin-Pollack, which is stated as follows.

> Any smooth map $f$ of the closed unit ball $B^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ into itself must have a fixed point; that is, $f(x) = x$ for some $x \in B^n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Map $[0,1]$ to itself by division by $2$.  Or the same for any convex compact set in Euclidean space, take a boundary point and shrink the whole set toward it by a factor of $1/2$.

Comment: or just choose a boundary point, and map the whole space to that point, i.e. the constant map.